# Google Maps Android API

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Using the Google Maps API, I was wondering if it were possible to implement a real-time feature into an app? My proposal is to provide informationg to users on free parking spots in their city. I am relatively in-experienced when designing for Android using Java.

I can't see installing the API being overly difficult, but some guidance on the possibility of real-time functionality would be appreciated.

Comment: You can show a map with markers.  The question is how you'd know where the free parking spots are, especially in realtime.  That isn't a feature of the maps API, you'd have to write it and generate the data yourself.

Comment: Thanks @GabeSechan for the response.

I think for my level of Android expertise that this idea is maybe a little far fetched. However, I would be interested to how to show a map with markers.

Am I able to add these markers myself?